# whenStreamingReady is not a function

Tags: sdk, soundcloud

It seems the soundcloud sdk changed again. The whenStreamingReady function does not exist. Its in the sdk, but not registered as public method.

Still in the doc:
http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#methods

Answer (score 0):

just fixed this on my website!

I had to include soundmanager manualy:

```
<script src="js/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js"></script>
<script>
    soundManager.setup({
          url: '../original/music/soundmanager2_debug.swf',
          flashVersion: 9, // optional: shiny features (default = 8)
          useFlashBlock : false,
          useHighPerformance : true,
          wmode : 'transparent',
          useFastPolling : true
        });
</script>
```

And then replace the

```
SC.whenStreamingReady(function(){ ...
```

By:

```
soundManager.setup({
    onready: function() { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: they've fixed it already, seems they pushed up some code they didn't mean to ;)